# Exploit user controllable C# code in webapp

Tags: .net, iis, angularjs

The application in question offers the option to create arbitrary C# code and execute it at any time. These could be considered macros to customize certain tasks. Say that a normal user, who would normally not be able to use this feature, found a way to elevate his privileges to an administrator role so that he can access this functionality.

What vulnerabilities may arise from this feature? I know it depends on lots of things but just in general, what's worth testing in this case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

...Total system compromise? "Arbitrary code execution" on a server - typically abbreviated "RCE" for "Remote Code Execution" - is generally considered to mean, in essence, "attacker wins". There are limitations, to be sure - most notably that by default the attacker will "only" be able to take over the account that the server process is running in - but the attacker isn't even limited to whatever their payload does directly; it can use a reverse shell or similar to proceed to execute anything else, too.

With sufficient sandboxing (either of that server, or better yet of the execution environment the remote code runs in) it can in fact be safe to do this (that's how all those "code playground" sites online work). Sandboxes, by their very nature, operate on the assumption that the attacker already has arbitrary code execution, and they try to prevent anything harmful from occurring (usually with, at best, qualified success; your browser is running a sandboxed rendering process that is running a sandboxed JS runtime which is executing a lot of arbitary Javascript to render this page, for example, but both the JS sandbox and the general browser sandbox have been breached in the past).

In general, RCE means you can attempt *any* other attack. Here is but a sample of things you can do, as an attacker, once you have RCE:

- You can attack the local network, trying to steal credentials or compromise other machines or pivot to more interesting hosts or attack metadata/control-plane servers, etc.
- You can attack the local machine, trying to gain elevation of privileges (to break out of a sandbox, become Administrator/root/LOCALSYSTEM, to gain kernel-mode execution, potentially even to break out of a VM...).
- You can attack the site's legitimate users, modifying the server such that you steal the user's credentials as they're entered, serve exploit kits and Trojaned downloads, carry out attacks on other sites that trust this one or at least where the user will trust this one...
- You can attack the Internet in general, adding the compromised machine to a botnet used for everything from DDoS attacks to a malware C&C node anonymizing/laundering malicious traffic.
- You can (of course) attack the owner of the server, stealing their files, their private keys, their intellectual property, their electricity and bandwidth (via cryptocurrency mining or similar), and even attempt extortion via ransomware.
- ... and so on. RCE means the attacker now essentially has moved their computer from somewhere out on the internet to running on your server host (or wherever else the attacker's code is executing). Every attack that the attacker could attempt if they were actually in that vantage point, they can attempt via RCE on your server.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer!